# Problem with event handling on QToolButton in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am developing an application, I have added a QToolBar object in that, and have added the QToolButton object on that, I have also connect the clicked() event with that but the problem is that the mouse click event don't work on QToolButton but when I bring focus on that using Tab, then space button works fine, but I want it with mouse click.. any idea? here is the code.

```
pToolBar = new QToolBar(this);

pToolBar->setAllowedAreas(Qt::NoToolBarArea);//NoToolBarAreaAllToolBarAreas
pToolBar->setFloatable(false);
pToolBar->setGeometry(300,0,160,30);

QToolButton *playButton=new QToolButton(pToolBar);

playButton->setIcon(QIcon("/images/play.png"));

playButton->setGeometry(10,0,40,30);

playButton->setToolTip("Play/Pause");

connect(playButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(playButtonClicked()));
```

Comment: What happens when you click on the button? Does your slot get called?

Comment: No it is not called.. button doesn't behave like a button, it looks like that it is not clicked.. but when I press spacebar slot is called and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

The Tool buttons are normally created when new *QAction* instances are created with *QToolBar::addAction()* or existing actions are added to a toolbar with *QToolBar::addAction()*.

Example:

```
QAction *newAct = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/new.png"), tr("&New"), this);
newAct->setShortcut(tr("Ctrl+N"));
newAct->setStatusTip(tr("Create a new file"));
connect(newAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(newFile()));
fileToolBar = addToolBar(tr("File"));
fileToolBar->addAction(newAct);
```

You can use *triggered* signal, This signal is emitted when the given action is triggered.

Your example:

```
QToolButton *playButton=new QToolButton(pToolBar);
connect(playButton, SIGNAL(triggered()),SLOT(playButtonClicked()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly adding the toolbutton to the toolbar. The following code works perfectly for me:

```
QToolBar *pToolBar = new QToolBar(this);

QToolButton *playButton=new QToolButton(pToolBar);
playButton->setIcon(QIcon("/images/play.png"));
playButton->setText("Play");
playButton->setToolTip("Play/Pause");
playButton->setGeometry(10,0,40,30);

QAction *a = pToolBar->addWidget(playButton);
a->setVisible(true);

connect(playButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(playButtonClicked()));
```

You should probably save the QAction pointer somewhere, since it's the easiest way to assign keyboard shortcuts, enable / disable the button etc. Let me know if this works for you. If it doesn't, perhaps posting a complete compilable example here will help us help you. You should be able to get a small demo program that shows your problem within one or two files.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

As jordenysp indirectly explains, the API is QAction centric